# Problems using overloaded extraction operator in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a Time class with the following overloading of the `>>` operator (they use HH:MM:SS format):

```
inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Hora& h) { //Our teacher says we have to implement it with inline and not with friend
    std::string aux;
    in >> aux;
    std::string aux_hora = aux.substr(0, 1);
    std::string aux_min = aux.substr(3, 4);
    std::string aux_seg = aux.substr(6, 7);
    h = Hora(std::stoi(aux_hora), std::stoi(aux_min), std::stoi(aux_seg));
    return in;
}
```

My problem is, how do I have to use the `cin` operator then in the `main.cpp`? I have tried writing this but the compiler says that I'm using uninitialized variables:

```
int hora, min, seg;
Hora h(hora, min, seg);
std::cin >> h;
```

If you need something else, please tell me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does `Hora` have a default constructor? (one that takes no parameters)?

Comment: Or try `Hora h (0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Welcome to SO. To have your question answered better please provide actual compiler warnings/erros not your interpretation of it. That should clearly point to line of code produced it.

Comment: you could (/should) consider to provide a default constructor (one that takes no parameters) for `Hora`. The `hora`. `min` and `seg` you use to construct `h` are overwritten anyhow

Comment: Are you sure you want aux_hora to be 1 character long, aux_min to be 4 characters long, and aux_seg to be 7 characters long?

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, it looks like your problem is in the test code, not the overloaded operator. This code:

```
int hora, min, seg;
Hora h(hora, min, seg);
```

...creates an `Hora` object, initialized from the current values of `hora`, `min`, and `seg`. But those haven't been initialized...

I'd try something like:

```
int hora=0, min=0, seg=0;
Hora h(hora, min, seg);
```

...and see if that fixes the warning. If not, it looks to me like the warning is probably in code you haven't shown us.

Obligatory aside: when/if you want to do something like this in real code (not just an assignment) you probably want to use [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) instead.